# DT: is there a way to display dataframe using r in google colab as interactive table?

Tags: r, dataframe, google-colaboratory, dt

Are you aware of a "nice" way to display the dataframe in colab using R, preferably as an interactive table?
I am trying the code below (which I typically use in rstudio) but it is not working in colab.

```
library(datasets)

data(iris)

library(DT)
DT::datatable(iris) #this typically displays a beautiful interactive html table, but not working with colab


#these display a simple table
View(iris)

fix(iris)
```

I did some search and looks like there is a nice way to display interactive table with filters in colab under python https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/data_table.ipynb#scrollTo=jcQEX_3vHOUz

but I could not find anything similar for R. Do you have any suggestions?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Good question!

So far I found two options:

1. a fancy one: `reactable::reactable()` (see [link](https://glin.github.io/reactable/articles/examples.html#basic-usage))
2. a simple one: `rmarkdown::paged_table()` (see [link](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/docs/reference/paged_table.html))